# How to detect right mouse click while left mouse button is pressed in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have the following:

```
<html>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).mousedown(function (e) {
                if (e.button == 2) //right click
                {
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }
                else //left click
                {
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If the right mouse button is clicked while the left mouse button is held down, the expected behavior is that the background color changes from blue to green.

This works in Firefox, but I'm not sure how to get this working in IE (7). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right+left mouse buttons sets `e.button==3` not 2.

Comment: Thanks! I should have assumed that the e.button values are different in IE & FF..